# Laravel 9, React, tailwind css not working

Tags: reactjs, laravel, tailwind-css

my tailwind `app.css` component is not working when i run `npm run dev` and `npm run build`
but in **Public/build/assets/app-css** the tailwind is listed. like this `

```
@tailwind base;@tailwind components;@tailwind utilities;
```

`
but it's not applying the tailwind. i don't know what is the problem.

this is my `welcome.blade`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel react</title>
        @viteReactRefresh
        @vite('resources/js/app.jsx')
    </head>
    <body class="antialiased">
        <div id="app">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

my `vite.config.js`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        react(),
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/js/app.jsx'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

my `tailwind.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [
      "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
      "./resources/**/*.jsx",
    ],
    theme: {
      extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
  }
```

my `resources/js/app.jsx

```
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css'

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import Routers from './components/router';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(
    <Routers/>
);
```

`

my `resources/css/app.css`

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

terminal run

```
npm install react@latest react-dom@latest
npm i @vitejs/plugin-react
npm run dev
php artisan serve
```

the tailwind css it's not working or applying on react and laravel, but when i run only react and tailwinds its working find when i run `npm run start` but on `npm run dev` or `npm run build` its not working

Answer (score -1):

In `vite.config.js` I'm missing this part:

```
...
    laravel({
        input: ['resources/css/app.css'],
```